# Passing in a scala function where a java handler is expected

Tags: java, scala, vert.x

I have scala code that is setup to handle HttpServerRequest on vertx.
One of the members (endHandler) expects a Handler where

```
public interface Handler<E> {
   void handle(E event);
}
```

What would the syntax be to pass in this from scala. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just pass scala function as you would pass lambda in java, at least not yet. You need to create an anonymous class like this:

```
new Handler[Int] {
  override def handle(event: Int): Unit = {
    // some code
  }
}
```

for convenience you can create helper method

```
implicit def functionToHandler[A](f: A => Unit): Handler[A] = new Handler[A] {
  override def handle(event: A): Unit = {
    f(event)
  }
}
```

If you make this method `implicit` then you are able to simply pass scala function

so to wrap up

```
def client(handler: Handler[Int]) = ??? // the method from java
val fun: Int => Unit = num => () // function you want to use
```

you can do this:

```
client(new Handler[Int] {
  override def handle(event: Int): Unit = fun(event)
})
```

with helper method:

```
client(functionToHandler(fun))
```

with implicit conversion:

```
client(fun)
```